# Unable to test toast message using protractor

Tags: protractor, toast

DOM for the toast message that i want to test is,

I tried the below code

When I run this code, I see the below error though it is able to locate the toast message. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
add_Button_loc = element(by.xpath("//button[@type='submit'][contains(text(),'Add')]"));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(add_Button_loc), 5000);
expect(add_Button_loc.isPresent()).toBe(true);
toastmsg = element(by.tagName("p-growl")).$('[value="aaa Batch saved successfully"]');
add_Button_loc.click();
expect(toastmsg.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

[10:17:26] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, p-growl) - the first result will be used

Failures:
1) ManageBatch Test Add Batch
  Message:
    Expected false to be true.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at UserContext. (C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\manageBatch.js:43:32)
        at C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\sarav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_

Comment: DOM Element is: <p-growl [(value)]="msgs"></p-growl>

Comment: Chances are likely you have multiple elements that match the selector `p-growl` and the first one listed in the DOM doesn't contain the value you are looking for. Elements can be present in the DOM and not visible. Would be a good idea to start there.

Comment: Thankn you, Since the toast message is visible only for sometime I am not able to find it. I see two p-growl in that page. Could you please tell me how to locate it if in case its a second element.

Comment: Show HTML with Toast, please

Comment: If you are using Chrome you can wait until the toast message pops up then hit F8 to insert a breakpoint. Then you can explore the HTML in devtools and figure out which one it is that you are looking for. An easier way to find this element would probably be `element(by.cssContainingText('p-growl', 'Batch saved successfully'));` Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable feedback. I was able to resolve it after using locator - using xpath - //span[contains(@class,'ui-growl-title')]